DIY RF Noise Bridge: Anyone use an SMD RF transformer with success?
I am building an RF noise bridge (DC-100MHz (200-400, even better) to replace one that failed in my Palomar Engineers antenna tuner.  I am using SMD components and have completed the implementation of the noise generator.
Now, I am designing the transformer stage between the generator and the Wheatstone bridge. I was planning on using an FT50-43 ferrite toroid, but I was curious whether any SMD RF transformers could be used.  I found that several companies make SMD RF transformers, such as those I've listed below, but I don't know whether they would be good solutions for an RF noise bridge.  There is no transmitting involved, so the requirements are simpler.
https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/TCM1-382WX+.pdf
https://productfinder.pulseelectronics.com/api/open/part-attachments/datasheet/cx2041nlt



Assuming the correct taps on the SMD RF transformer, would one be a good substitute for a wrapped ferrite toroid?



PROPOSED CIRCUIT USING MINI-CIRCUIT'S TC1-1T+ RF TRANSFORMER

Thanks for your comments,
Mike

For a noise bridge, transformer insertion loss is of less importance than balance between the two bridge arms. Both arms ideally have the same amplitude and (opposing) phase.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Good point.  I will update the posting.  Thanks

The answer is likely yes. But we can't know for sure until you provide more details on your exact circuit and your intentions.
But even without the additional information, there's no obvious reason why using SMD RF transformers wouldn't work where a FT50-43 toroid would. The RF transformers you referenced will have better characteristics in almost every category over the FT50-43, except power-handling capacity and possibly price. Power handling shouldn't be a real issue in a noise bridge.

Thank you for your comments!  I want to use a Mini-Circuits TC1-1T+ RF Transformer in my RF Noise Bridge. Based on the specifications, it seems like it would work well, but I am not a professional electrical engineer.  I've attached an image showing the circuit and would appreciate your feedback about using the TC1-1T+.
https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=TC1-1T%2B

I've added the circuit image to the original post in case you'd like to  see it.
